# Differentiate between focus event triggered by keyboard/mouse

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using jquery ui autocomplete and want to decipher between focus events triggered by keyboard interaction and mouse interaction. How would I go about this?

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        ...
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        // If focus triggered by keyboard interaction
            alert('do something');
        // If focus event triggered by mouse interaction
            alert('do something else');
    }
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Well, the only way I know of to focus with a mouse is the `click` event, but how to recognize the keyboard focus - good question. I'd assume that checking what key was pressed (TAB only?) would be the right idea, but I'm not too sure. Maybe checking if `click` was fired on `focus()`? Not sure how to do these off the top of my head, but maybe this will help some one who wants to take a stab at this.

Comment: The two things I am trying to segregate are actually using arrow keys to move down/up the autocomplete list, and hovering over the autocomplete list items with the mouse. UI autocomplete handles mouse clicks by selecting the item and closing autocomplete - taking a select parameter seperately.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is to have a handler listen in on the `keypress` and `click` events, and toggle a boolean flag on/off. Then on the `focus` handler of your input, you can just check what the value of your flag is, and go from there.

Probably something like

```
var isClick;
$(document).bind('click', function() { isClick = true; })
           .bind('keypress', function() { isClick = false; })
           ;

var focusHandler = function () {
    if (isClick) {
        // clicky!
    } else {
        // tabby!
    }
}

$('input').focus(function() {
    // we set a small timeout to let the click / keypress event to trigger
    // and update our boolean
    setTimeout(focusHandler,100);
});
```

Whipped up a small working prototype on jsFiddle (don't you just love this site?). [Check it out if you want.](http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/vsEg7/1/)

Of course, this is all running off a `focus` event on an `<input>`, but the `focus` handler on the autocomplete works in the same way.

The `setTimeout` will introduce a bit of lag, but at 100ms, it might be negligible, based on your needs.

Comment: Also a great idea - but I'm actually not looking for click, but for hover : )

Comment: In that case, it shouldn't be too hard to switch out the `click` handler for a `hover` (or better yet I think, a `mousein`) handler. Let me see if I can whip up something in a while. :D

Comment: setTimeout for the focus handler. Great idea.

Comment: the keydown event is more reliable, i think

Comment: @emfi yes, keydown also detects tab, alt, ctrl and such

Answer (score 9):

The easiest and most elegant way I've found of achieving this is to use the "[What Input?](https://github.com/ten1seven/what-input)" library. It's tiny (~2K minified), and gives you access to the event type both in scripts:

```
if (whatInput.ask() === 'mouse') {
  // do something
}
```

...and also (via a single data attribute that it adds to the document `body`) styles:

```
[data-whatinput="mouse"] :focus,
[data-whatinput="touch"] :focus {
  // focus styles for mouse and touch only
}
```

I particularly like the fact that where you just want a different visual behaviour for mouse / keyboard it makes it possible to do that in the stylesheet (where it really belongs) rather than via some hacky bit of event-checking Javascript (though of course if you do need to do something that's not just purely visual, the former approach lets you handle it in Javascript instead).

Answer (score 6):

You should actually be able to determine this from the event-Object that is passed into the focus-event. Depending on your code structure this might be different, but there is usually a property called `originalEvent` in there, which might be nested to some depth. Examine the `event`-object more closely to determine the correct syntax. Then test on `mousenter` or `keydown` via regular expression. Something like this:

```
focus: function(event, ui){
  if(/^key/.test(event.originalEvent.originalEvent.type)){
    //code for keydown
  }else{
    //code for mouseenter and any other event
  }
}
```

Comment: `event.originalEvent.originalEvent.type` gives me `Cannot read property 'type' of undefined` in Chrome v34

Comment: The problem is that ```originalEvent``` is not normalized across browsers AFAIK

Comment: Yeah, that would be a perfect solution, but it seems to be supported only in Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget#Browser_compatibility and they  discourage using it in production. +1 for the try though.

Comment: As of Nov 2020, this approach appears to work flawlessly on Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Edge. It's supported even though the Firefox docs say it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled using `mousedown` event, see my example below.

```
this.focusFrom = 'keyboard' => 

onFocus = () => {
    if (this.focusFrom === 'keyboard') {
        // do something when focus from keyboard
    }
}

handleMouseDown = () => {
    this.focusFrom = 'mouse';
}

handleOnClick = () => {
    this.focusFrom = 'keyboard';
}
```

Comment: @Tyler2P what do you mean? Looks like ES6

Comment: This wont work since `focus` fires before `mousedown` and `keydown`.

Comment: `focus` does not usually fire before `mousedown`, but I've never been able to find anything in the spec that guarantees the order anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago. But in case if anyone wants a solution, here is a sample code in plain JS with text input.

Console will also tell you the order of events that is happened.

```js
const testInput = document.getElementById('testInput');
let click = false;

testInput.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  console.log('mousedown --->');
  click = true;
});


testInput.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  console.log('keydown --->');
  click = false;
});


testInput.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
  console.log('focus --->');
  if (click) {
    testInput.placeholder = "Through Mouseclick";
    testInput.classList.remove('key');
    testInput.classList.add('expand');
  } else {
    testInput.placeholder = "Through keyboard";
    testInput.classList.remove('expand');
    testInput.classList.add('key');
  }
});

testInput.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
   // Reset flags and remove classes
   testInput.placeholder = "Enter your text   ";
   testInput.classList.remove('key');
   testInput.classList.remove('expand');
   click = false;
});
```

```css
input[type='text'] {
  transition: width 200ms;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type='text'].key {
  outline: 1px solid blue;
}

input[type='text'].expand {
  outline: 2px solid green;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#dummy-link"> Dummy Link </a>
<br/>
<input type="text" id="testInput" placeholder="Enter your text "/>
```