# CSS Cross-Browser Outline Suppression On Click

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser, outline

I have a menu structure that looks like this:

HTML:

```
<li>
  <a href="#page">
    <b>Recover Account</b>
  </a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
#nav ul li a
{
  color: #889DBF;
  display: block;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a b
{
  display: block;
  padding-right: 21px;
}

#nav ul li.current a
{
  background: url('/images/nav-left.png') no-repeat;
  color: #111B35;
}

#nav ul li.current a b
{
  background: url('/images/nav-right.png') no-repeat 100% 0;
  color: #111B35;
}
```

I've been trying for many many days to find a cross-browser solution to suppress outline style on click while keeping it enabled with tab navigation.

None of the solutions written on the following pages are working for me:
http://people.opera.com/patrickl/experiments/keyboard/test
http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/Removing-Dotted-Border-on-Clicked-Links

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Any solution (CSS only, JS, CSS+JS) is welcome.
Many thanks in advance!

```
[TL;DR]
Outline On Click -> DISABLED
Outline On Tab Navigation -> ENABLED
Any cross-browser solution? Thanks!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use **JavaScript**, so that you can differentiate between **keyboard** and **mouse** event triggers.

Part of the answer for your question was already posted in [Differentiate between focus event triggered by keyboard/mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653332/differentiate-between-focus-event-triggered-by-keyboard-mouse/5654509#5654509)

And here is the complete solution using the [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) javascript framework:

```
var isClick;
$(document).bind('click', function() { isClick = true; })
           .bind('keypress', function() { isClick = false; })
           ;
var userInterestHandlers = {
     on: function (e) {
        var $self = $(this);
        var classname =isClick ? 'mouse' : 'keyboard';
        $self.addClass(classname);
    }
    off: function (e) {
        var $self = $(this);
        $self.removeClass('mouse keyboard');
    }
}

$('a').bind ('focus active', userInterestHandlers.on);
$('a').bind ('blur', userInterestHandlers.off);
```

Afterwards just define the desired style in the `a.keyboard` or `a.mouse` **`CSS`** classes.

Comment: This solution is partially working for me only with Chrome. What is the active event? I cannot find it on jQuery documentation.

Comment: @Zarathos active is initially to do with CSS. It is the state of an anchor/link when it's pressed down, clicked down, touched down..

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
a:active {
    outline:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: But the poster specified he wants the outline to remain for keyboard based navigation.  That suppresses it on both keyboard and clicks.  I'd personally just do `:active`.

Comment: Ah I misread the TL;DR. I thought it was being enabled on focus and that wasn't the desired result :)

Comment: Right guys, I would like to keep it for tab based navigation!

Comment: Cool if this worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer :) Thanks!