# Determine whether React `onFocus` event was triggered by Mouse, Keyboard, Programmatic?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Because React simply says that the `event.type` is `focus` I'm not sure what I can do to determine this.

I need to run some code only if the focus was not initiated by the mouse.

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should use duck typing, e.g. only MouseEvents have pageX, pageY properties, so

```
if (e.pageX || pageY) -> MouseEvent
```

Keyboard Event have locale, location

```
if (e.locale || location) -> KeyboardEvent
```

You can find all differences in official documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#supported-events

Answer (score 0):

Use some other event that only applies to the keyboard. Check this other post: [Differentiate between focus event triggered by keyboard/mouse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653332/differentiate-between-focus-event-triggered-by-keyboard-mouse)

For React you want to use onKeyDown or onKeyPress. You can check these events here: https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html#keyboard-events